# Как записать результат цикла for в .txt документ?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно сделать так, чтобы результат цикла for записывался в .txt. Например,
`aab aac aba`, только каждый раз с новой строки.

```
import itertools
noc = input('число >>> ')
ltr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

for i in itertools.product(ltr, repeat=int(noc)):
    print(''.join(i))
```

Comment: С чем у вас сложность - с открытием файла?

Comment: С открытием и записью в файл

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp это Вам поможет

Comment: @NoScoPe096 Ну это уж совсем элементарно, работа с файлами описана в сотнях руководств по питону, доступных в интернете элементарным поиском

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Открытие и запись в файл c циклом производятся следующим образом:**

```
STR_DATA = ['Str1', 'Str2', 'Str3']

with open('f.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
  for i in range(len(STR_DATA)):
     file.write(STR_DATA[i] + '\n')
```

Можете использовать этот код по вашему усмотрению, в зависимости от задачи.